# Best practice updating data based on user information with Firebase/Android?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

How should I proceed to build or update data based on Firebase user information ?

I'm building an app where people can posts messages in an open feed. On screen, these posts and replies contain the username and profile picture. I'm using Firebase to store these posts and the users.

The question is should I "build" and store a post with the profile pic (url) and username stored, "hardcoded", in that post or retrieve data stored in the corresponding user subtree in Firebase for each post?
If a user updates his profile picture, the first solution means searching through all posts and updating every corresponding post and replies but is quicker in loading the feed, the second seems more efficient for a large number of posts and users but more laggy on execution.

This is my first time with Firebase and with Android. What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common practice is to store the profile picture in [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). When uploading the picture you need to get the coresponding url of that picture. Having that url, you can easily store it in the [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) or in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). Every time you need to display the picture, just simply use the reference of that picture. If a user will change the profie picture, there will be no need for doing something. Using that reference will display in every place the new picture.